# Integral of exponential of squared linear combination of variables

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

I would like to solve the following integral:
$$
\int{\exp{\left(\left(y_{ij}-\sum_{k=1}^M{A_{ik}r_{jk}}\right)^2\right)}dr_{11}\ldots dr_{PM}},
$$
where index $i$ ranges from $1$ to $N$, $j$ from $1$ to $P$.
I know it is closely related to the marginalisation of Gaussian process regression coefficients:
$$
\int{\exp{\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\overline{y}-\overline{\overline{F}}\overline{\beta}\right)^T\overline{\overline{\Sigma}}^{-1}\left(\overline{y}-\overline{\overline{F}}\overline{\beta}\right)\right)}}d\overline{\beta},
$$
see e.g. [Andrianakis and Challenor, section 3.1](http://www.mucm.ac.uk/Pages/Downloads/Technical%20Reports/11-03%20YA%20PC%20Parameter%20Estimation%20for%20Gaussian%20process%20emulators.pdf)
however, I can't seem to find any derivation of this either.

Thanks in advance.